# how to make sure one function runs after other two, one of which may not be run at all?

Tags: lua

i know the title isn't really clear but i couldn't explain it properly without writing the whole question.

i have 3 functions, for simplicity let's say they are a() b() and c(), what i need to do is to run c() only after both a() and b(), normally i could simply do something like this

```
function a()
    --code--
    a_is_done = true
    c()
end

function b()
    --code--
    b_is_done = true
    c()
end

function c()
    if a_is_done and b_is_done then
        --code---
        a_is_done = false
        b_is_done = false
    end
end
```

however there are cases where either a() or b() may not be called at all but i still need c() to happen, since a() and b() are callbacks from other code i can never know if they are both happening or not and in which order, how can i handle this?

Comment: Why not have `if a_is_done or b_is_done then`?

Comment: because then c() would be executed 2 times, one after a() one after b()

Comment: Unless you define some timeout on which to run c() your problem has no solution.  Why? Not knowing if a() or b() will ever be called you would have to wait indefinitely just in case they are eventually called.  Now, if you have a recurring timeout, you can simply call c() during the timeout.